# Who took the Star Wars RPG license over from WotC in 2011?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition, star-wars, games-industry, intellectual-property

Lucas Licensing and Wizards of the Coast announced in the beginning of 2011 that WotC is not renewing their license for the [Star Wars RPG](http://www.starwars.com/games/othergames/news20100128wotc/index.html).

Who has taken it over from them? Solid facts please (as soon as they become available, in case no-one *here* has them *yet*.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fantasy Flight Games now has the licence:

> Fantasy Flight Games is pleased to announce that it has entered a
>   comprehensive licensing partnership with Lucasfilm Ltd. for the
>   worldwide rights to publish card, roleplaying, and miniatures games
>   set in the popular Star Wars universe!

Source: [StarWars.com (August 2, 2011)](http://www.starwars.com/games/othergames/fantasyflight_starwars/index.html)

Answer (score 6):

Mongoose Publishing's Matthew Sprang claimed he approached Lucasfilm, looking to obtain a license for a Star Wars Roleplaying Game; He was apparently told that someone else already has the license.

Most major companies have denied having the license.

The following have said it isn't them:

- Far Future Enterprises
- Steve Jackson Games
- Eden Studios
- Margaret Weiss Productions
- Paizo
- Green Ronin

As have a dozen+ indie publishers.

Here's where the blog post is quoted:
http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?t=552022

And here's the quote of Matt:

> In other A Call to Arms news, I can now report that we did not manage to grab the licence we were chasing for the game - Star Wars. We weren't really expecting this one to happen (we made a sideways reference to it in the State of the Mongoose), but we got much further along than we thought we would.
>
> The interesting thing is why our negotiations ended - another company beat us to it. We are not going to reveal who this is (you have heard of them), as that is their fanfare to blow. However, I am sure many will find it intriguing that the licence covers card games, RPGs, and... miniatures. Now, the company concerned is not known for its miniatures lines, which will probably put paid to my dream of 28mm multipart/multipose Stormtroopers.